# ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool putObject () s3Client Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm uploading image files to s3 using the s3 aws client in my java application, but sometimes I've been getting the error

```
ERROR 9 --- [io-8080-exec-27] b.c.i.h.e.handler.HttpExceptionHandler   : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
```

but I haven't identified the reason for this error to occur and what solution I need to implement. I observed in the documentation the implementation of a ClientConfiguration setMaxConnections and passing it to the AmazonS3ClientBuilder object, but I believe that this would be increasing the problem and not actually correcting it, would I be correct?

I did not find detail why this problem with connection pooling occurs when using putObject (), if someone knows the reason or can explain through my implementation why this problem occurs. In our application there is also a configuration for SQS Config for queues

**S3Config**

```
public class S3Config {

    @Bean        
    public AmazonS3 s3client() {
            return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .build();
    }
}
```

**Service Upload**

```
public List<String> uploadImage(Long id, List<MultipartFile> files) throws Exception {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Product product = this.productService.findById(id);
    List<String> imgPath = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
      String name = (product.getName() + this.brandService.findBrandById(product.getBrand()).getName() + rand.nextInt(999999)).replaceAll(" ", "-");
      String fullPath = this.s3Service.uploadImageFile(
              file,'.' + Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()).split("\\.")[1], 
              name, 
              awsBucketProperties.getName(), 
              awsBucketProperties.getEndpoint());
      imgPath.add(this.utils.removeImageDomain(fullPath));
    }
    return imgPath;
  }
```

**Service S3**

```
public String uploadImageFile(final MultipartFile file, final String ext, final String filename, final String bucketName, final String bucketEndpoint) throws IOException {

        byte[] imageData = file.getBytes();
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
        String s3FileName = filename + ext;
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(stream.available());

        try {
            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3FileName, stream, metadata)
                    .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
        } catch (AmazonClientException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return String.format("%s/%s", bucketEndpoint, s3FileName);
    }
```

Comment: How many concurrent puts do you have in your application? Is it less than connection pool configured? Did you check that some connections didn't leak left unclosed for some reason? Is this helpful: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1405 ?

Comment: @ByerN My rule is, on the front I break a block of 30 files and 3 blocks with 10 files and make the request on my back-end. Where in the example I perform a for always in 10 files sent one at a time.

I didn’t even implement a metrics to check for leaks in connections, I didn’t even think about this alternative

Comment: Usually connection pool has to be configured according to concurrency of your application. If you don't have any problem with leaking connections, try increasing pool. Sometimes it's better to set higher number of maximum waiting connection (if it's possible) or change implementation to not do these all at once (queue, reactive streams, throttling etc).

Comment: @ByerN Got it, thanks for the reply. In case I am going to make this diagnosis, I was left with this doubt because I send one file at a time as shown in the for loop, why does it burst the connection pool? Does it create multiple threads for a single upload?

Comment: As far as I remember s3 client could be sync or async. I don't remember how the choice is made and which one exactly is in your application. Worth to check. putObject returns result so you can check what is the status of the request.